# Como substituir um valor específico de uma query string de uma url através do PHP usando um array?

Tags: php

Eu tenho a seguinte url que me é retornada por um webservice numa determinada parte da minha aplicação. Mas ela vem com uma query string que determinada o tamanho da imagem (de acordo com o parâmetro `width` essa url me trás a imagem com tamanho diferente).

Gostaria de poder substituir somente esse valor da query string, o `width`, e subsituir por um outro.

Quero fazer isso a partir de um `array`. Ou seja, eu vou ter um `array` com os valores que quero substituir na query string dessa url, porém não posso remover os outros.

Por exemplo. Se tenho essa url:

```
 http://site.com/images/?sistema=3&size=500&type=png;
```

Quero transformá-la, transformando o valor de `500` para `200`, tornando-a assim:

```
 http://site.com/images/?sistema=3&size=200&type=png;
```

Como quero fazer através de um `array`, preciso de algo assim:

```
 // retornado pelo webservice

 $url = 'http://site.com/images/?sistema=3&size=500&type=png';

 $url = transforma_query_string($url, array('size' => 200));
```

Isso teria que retornar:

```
'http://site.com/images/?sistema=3&size=200&type=png;'
```

Como eu poderia fazer para criar essa função em PHP? Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: como está seu array?

Comment: Olha o último exemplo... `array('size' => 200)`... Eu já coloquei na pergunta :)

Comment: Não seria mais facil usar um `str_replace` não?
Dessa forma: `$size = 200;` `$url = 'http://site.com/images/?sistema=3&size=500&type=png';` e na hora de printar colocava assim `$url = str_replace( '&size=500', '&size='.$size, transforma_query_string($url) );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Opção específica

```
function transforma_query_string($str, $parameters) {
    // considerando que a url será sempre size=500 e que outros parâmetros nunca terão o valor 500:
    return str_replace('500', $parameters['size'], $str);
}

$url = 'http://site.com/images/?sistema=3&size=500&type=png';
echo transforma_query_string($url, array('size' => 200));
```

## Opção genérica

Algo mais genérico, onde poderá usar para diferentes URLs:

```
function foo($url, $new_query) {
    $arr = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($arr['query'], $query);
    return $arr['scheme'].'://'.$arr['host'].$arr['path'].'?'.http_build_query(array_replace($query, $new_query));
}

$url = 'http://site.com/images/?sistema=3&size=500&type=png';
echo foo($url, array('size' => 200));
```

Comment: Para criar algo reutilizável, detesto repetir código...

Comment: entendi.. então vc quer algo genérico que possa modificar qualquer parâmetro de uma query string, independente da url?

Comment: updated........

Comment: Isso mesmo, valeu :D

Answer (score 1):

```
function transforma_query_string($url,$dados){
   $url=explode('?',$url,2);//separa o link dos argumentos
   $link=$url[0].'?';//adiciona o ? para ficar pronto para os argumentos
   $argumentos=explode('&',$url[1]);//divide os argumentos
   foreach($argumentos AS $i){//corre todos os argumentos
       $temp=explode('=',$i);//separa o index e valor
       if (array_key_exists($temp[0],$dados)){//verifica se é para alterar
           $temp[1]=$dados[$temp[0]];//altera
       }
       $link.=$link==$url[0].'?'?$temp[0].'='.$temp[1]:'&'.$temp[0].'='.$temp[1];//Adiciona ao link
   }
   return $link;// envia o link alterado
}
```

Comment: Resposta boa. Só não entendi porque não usou `http_build_query`. Achei que o foreach foi desnecessário, sem contar que você teria que verificar o caso onde a url possui um array de elementos, como no caso de `x[]=1&x[]=2`,