# PHP remover um trecho da URI com expressao regular

Tags: php, regex

Tenho a seguinte uri

```
$uri = "http://www.meudominio.com.br/pagina.php?campo=teste&ordem=2&cor=azul"
```

como remover o `"ordem=2`" da url acima com expressão regular, sabendo que o valor da ordem, hora pode ser 2, 3, 4 e etc?

`http://www.meudominio.com.br/pagina.php?campo=teste&cor=azul`

poderia tentar assim?

```
$arr_nova_uri = explode("ordem=", $uri);
$nova_uri = $arr_nova_uri[0].substr($arr_nova_uri[1], 2);
```

Comment: possivel duplicata de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123638/4793

Answer (score 7):

Expressão regular:

```regex
/(?:(\?)|&)ordem=\d+(?(1)(?:&|$)|(&|$))/
```

Substituição:

```
$1$2
```

Código:

```
$uri   = 'http://www.meudominio.com.br/pagina.php?campo=teste&ordem=2&cor=azul';
$re    = '/(?:(\?)|&)ordem=\d+(?(1)(?:&|$)|(&|$))/';
$subst = '$1$2';

$nova_uri = preg_replace($re, $subst, $uri);

echo $nova_uri;
```

Resultado:

```
http://www.meudominio.com.br/pagina.php?campo=teste&cor=azul
```

Comment: Fechou!... perfeito..

Comment: ah uma pequena gaf caso seja o ultimo parâmetro : [Veja](https://regex101.com/r/TfUv0i/1), mas nada que interfira muito. A menos que se pegue todos os parâmetros por array.

Comment: Sugestão, não se preocupe com o que ver depois, [exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/TfUv0i/2).

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Obrigado pela sugestão. `&` é válido no fim. Mas eu editei a resposta para considerá-lo. Seu exemplo tem um problema no último caso. Não está sendo validado que só são números e substitui o `?` por `&`.

Comment: Caso queira inverter a ordem dos parâmetros, basta remover o &ordem=N
     $re = '/&ordem=\d+/';
     $str = 'http://www.meudominio.com.br/pagina.php?     campo=teste&ordem=2&cor=azul';
     $result = preg_replace($re,'', $str);

Comment: @MarcosXavier Tente este outro exemplo: `http://www.meudominio.com.br/pagina.php?ordem=2&campo=teste`

Comment: Simples. 
https://regex101.com/r/YIR8IP/1

Comment: @MarcosXavier Não é tão simples: `pagina.php?desordem=2FFF&campo=teste`

Comment: @Mariano ficou muito bom, se quiser pode [reduzir](https://regex101.com/r/TfUv0i/3), eu nunca tinha usado o `(?(R))`, bem interessante.

Comment: @Guilherme Obrigado! Pode. Mas eu queria validar [este caso](https://regex101.com/r/TfUv0i/4).

Comment: @Mariano entendi :D

Comment: @Mariano Da uma olhada no post http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159428/php-remover-um-trecho-da-uri-com-expressao-regular#159549

Comment: @kurole Se manifeste informando se sua questão já foi resolvida, seria legal se puder revisar suas perguntas e ver se alguma resposta merece o voto e a aceitação. Leia [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/53463) e clique no botão **✔️**.

Answer (score 5):

No meu Github eu criei um [gist](https://gist.github.com/wallacemaxters/8022c41d747322a75eba) com uma função para fazer operações como essa de maneira reutilizável. Além do mais, preferi não usar expressão regular, pois geralmente essas costumam a custar mais em termos de performance.

Essa função permite remover, substituir ou adicionar parâmetros numa determinada url. Se ela já tiver Query String, será substituído ou adicionado.

Veja:

```
function url_replace_query($url, array $parameters)
{
    $parts = parse_url($url) + [
        'scheme' => 'http',
        'query'  => NULL,
        'path'   => NULL,
    ];
    if (! isset($parts['host'])) return false;
    parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
    $parameters += $query;
    $newQueryString = http_build_query($parameters);
    return $parts['scheme'] . '://' . $parts['host'] . $parts['path'] . '?' . $newQueryString;
}
```

Você pode usá-la assim:

```
$url_sem_ordem = url_replace_query("http://www.meudominio.com.br/pagina.php?campo=teste&ordem=2&cor=azul", ['ordem' => null])
```

Resultado:

```
'http://www.meudominio.com.br/pagina.php?campo=teste&cor=azul'
```

Comment: Interessante é, mas achei muita balaca para coisa simples. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Se o parâmetro ordem é alfanumérico pode usar o seguinte exemplo.

Ps. Postei aqui para os comentários não se estenderem muito

Run in https://regex101.com/r/YIR8IP/2

```
$re = '/&?ordem=(\d+)?(\w+)?/';
$str = 'pagina.php?campo=teste&ordem=2&cor=azul
pagina.php?ordem=2&campo=teste
pagina.php?ordem=2FFF&campo=teste
pagina.php?ordem=FFF&campo=teste
 ';
$subst = '';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```